# Error trying to connect to iscsi target with Windows initiator on W2K3

Tags: windows-server-2003, iscsi, qnap

I am trying to connect to an iScsi array (hosted on a QNAP 859URP+) from my W2K3, via a 2nd NIC.

I have my QNAP 859URP+ connected through LAN1 to my switch. It gets it's IP from our DHCP server.

I want to connect LAN2 directly to the server. I have the following settings:

```
QNAP LAN1 (connected to switch)
IP: 192.168.0.9
MASK: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.254


QNAP LAN2 (connected to the 2nd NIC on the server)
IP: 192.168.111.1 (default)
MASK: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: NONE
```

On the server, the 2NIC that is connected to the QNAP LAN2 has the following:

```
IP: 192.168.111.2
MASK: 255.255.255.0
GATEWAY: NONE
```

(first NIC is DHCP'ed)

I am able to ping to the 192.168.111.1 from the server (and not from any other pc/server on the network - that's good), but when trying to access/add from the Windows iScsi Initiator - I get an error: connection failed.

- Port is the default 3260
- no firewalls are installed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have found the problem to be a security setting on the QNAP. I have limited access to the QNAP from IP range of: 192.168.0.1-254. Changing that solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem to be a security setting on the QNAP. I have limited access to the QNAP from IP range of: 192.168.0.1-254. Changing that solved the problem